# Group of sub group

Tags: sql, oracle

Given the next table :

```
+---+------------+-----------------------------+
|  ID |     A      |      B      |  C          |
+-----+------------+-------------+-------------+
| 1   | TRUE       | FALSE       |   123       |
| 2   | FALSE      | FALSE       |   123       |
| 3   | FALSE      | FALSE       |   123       |  
| 4   | FALSE      | FALSE       |   222       |
| 5   | TRUE       | FALSE       |   222       |  
| 6   | FALSE      | FALSE       |   222       |
| 7   | FALSE      | FALSE       |   333       |  
| 8   | FALSE      | TRUE        |   333       |
| 9   | FALSE      | TRUE        |   444       |  
| 10  | FALSE      | FALSE       |   444       |
+-----+------------+-------------+-------------+
```

1. Grouping by column C there can be only one **TRUE** in this group ,  value in column A or B - Get ID .
2. If **TRUE** value not exists in A , bring B - get ID

The desired output here will be :

```
+-----+------------+-------------+-------------+
|  ID |     A      |      B      |  C          |
+-----+------------+-------------+-------------+
| 1   |    TRUE    | FALSE       |   123       |
| 5   |    TRUE    | FALSE       |   222       |
| 8   |   FALSE    | TRUE        |   333       |
| 9   |   FALSE    | TRUE        |   444       |  
+-----+--------------------------+-------------+
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Where is your code! What have you tried so far?

Comment: PL/SQL is a programming language. What does that have to do with your question? Please tag your DBMS (Oracle, PostgreSQL, MySQL, ...) instead.

Comment: Column data types? DBMS?

Answer (score 1):

You want to show the record where either `A` or `B` is `'TRUE'`? What is so difficult about that?

```
select * from mytable where a = 'TRUE' or b = 'TRUE' order by c;
```

Comment: Does Oracle support boolean? `... where a or b`.

Comment: @jarlh: No, Oracle SQL does not support `BOOLEAN`. And it's not the OP who tagged this request with Oracle. We don't know the DBMS and we don't know whether TRUE and FALSE here mean boolean or string. I took them to mean string, which is available in every RDBMS :-)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to achieve a priority between `A` and `B`. Try `NOT EXISTS` and `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT ID, A, B, C FROM your_table WHERE A = 'True'
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, A, B, C FROM your_table WHERE B = 'True' AND NOT EXISTS
   (
        SELECT 1 FROM your_table t2 WHERE t2.ID = ID AND A = 'True'
   )
```